# Select all records in a date range even if no records present

Tags: mysql, date

I have a database of employees and their attendance. I have to create the date range reports of attendance.

Attendance Database table

[image: Database Schema]

I am using below query

```
SELECT a.* FROM attendance a WHERE a.user_id=10 AND (a.date BETWEEN '2017-01-06' AND '2017-01-10')
```

Result:-
[image: Result by My Query]

I also want records for all given date range but some dates record is not present in database and i want that dates shows null values to corresponds to that dates as shown in below image.

[image: Final Output I want]

Comment: I think there is something else wrong because the query isn't wrong, it just filters the date and the user_id, which are in both cases correct. can you try to remove the `a.` and just do a normal query? (SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE user_id=10 AND (date BETWEEN '2017-01-06' AND '2017-01-10')

Comment: One would normally handle issues of data display (such as missing rows) in application code

Comment: @Tosfera In the database we don't have records for that dates (07,08) but i want the response including missing date of provided interval that i shown in the above image.

Comment: @Strawberry i can write the application code to handle this situation. It would better if we get response that we want rather then writing a code.

Comment: So ultimately, you output this to a command line window? :-(

Comment: @Strawberry i didn't get you.

Comment: Does the end user use a Command Line Interface (or something like PHPMyAdmin) to review and interrogate the data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132898/discussion-between-manoj-kumar-and-strawberry).

Comment: Did you find any answer for this?

Comment: @FaisalNaseer No

Comment: OK no problem I handled it in my application logic

Comment: Great @FaisalNaseer, I also achieved with application logic

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I am not able to run it but the idea is to generate a date range based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157282/generate-days-from-date-range).

1. Use this date range as derived table `d`.
2. Do a `d` `left join` `attendance` adding your condition so you will get all the columns for matching data and `null` for not matching data.
3. This will give you rest of the data, except employee id. I suggest you can hardcode it in select query.

   ```
   select * from 
       (select a.Date 
           from 
           (
               select curdate() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY as Date
               from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
               cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
               cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
           ) a
           where a.Date between '2017-01-06' AND '2017-01-10' 
       ) d
   left join 
       attendance a
   on d.date = a.date
   where 
   a.user_id=10
   ```

Comment: i executed in the database this will not work... i have already googled about it and visited tried all the solution that i found but no single one worked for me..

Comment: Why will this not work? Will u get any error? It would be easier if you used sqlfiddle.com and create sample tables so one can try running the queries.